# Inline creation of snippet in a streamfield block (Wagtail 2.3+)

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

so lets say I have the following models set up for Wagtail:

```
@register_snippet
class MySnippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    panels = [FieldPanel('name'),]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name',]

class MyPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('mysnippet', SnippetChooserBlock(required=False, label='MySnippet', target_model='MySnippet')),
    ], blank=True, help_text='')

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body', heading='Stuff to add'),
    ]
```

My client will be creating a lot of `MySnippet` items as they go. It's going to be super awkward for them to move to another view in their CMS, create a `MySnippet`, then come back to their main `MyPage` editor to choose it.

**Q1 Is there a simple way to add a `SnippetChooseOrInlineCreate()` block so clients can add new `MySnippet`s as they create `MyPage`s?**

**Q2 If there's no existing simple way, how would you recommend approaching this?**

Comment: can you explain more about the relation between `snippets` and `page` ?

Comment: In this case, there's no FK, 121 or M2M relation between the MyPage and the MySnippet model in this case, if that's what you mean, @waLLe?

Comment: why don't you use InlinePanel ?

Comment: I wasn't aware that it might be possible to use *Panels as *Blocks, because no actual FK relation is made, but will try it on Monday.